# How to remove objects out a jsonlist with filters?

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I want to remove certain objects out of my array with filters.

This is the code that generates the array (JSON parser)

```
protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {

            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
            JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

            for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {

                try {
                    JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(i);

                    String naam = c.getString("actNaam");

                    String type = c.getString("actType");
                    String datum = c.getString("actDatum");

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    map.put("actNaam", naam);
                    map.put("actType", type);
                    map.put("actDatum", datum);


                    jsonlist.add(map);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;

        }
    }
```

This is the code where the array should be filtered befor displaying.

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
            if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonlist.size(); i++) {
                if (wandeling == false && type == "wandeling") {
                //Here we want to remove the types that have the string wandeling
                //The boolean wandeling has to be false befor the items should be removed
                }
                if (fiets == false && type == "fiets") {
                //Here we want to remove the types that have the string wandeling
                }
                if (excursie == false && type == "excursie") {
                //Here we want to remove the types that have the string wandeling
                }
            }

            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter
                    (context, jsonlist, R.layout.list_activity,

                            new String[]{naam, type, datum},
                            new int[]{R.id.ActNaam, R.id.ActType, R.id.Actdatum});

            setListAdapter(adapter);

            lv = getListView();

        }
```

We are making a list from a json file. The list has 3 item: naam, type and datum.
We want the user to be able to 'filter' through the list with buttons. The button are the ones that give back the boolean values for wandeling, fiets and excursie.

So for example when the button 'wandeling' is not clicked (false) we want to remove every item from the array that has the type 'wandeling';
The types are safed in the json file with strings like this:

```
"actType":"wandeling"
"actType":"fiets"
"actType":"excursie"
```

Sorry for my bad English and thanks for helping!

Comment: use `String.equals` instead of `==` for comparing Strings

Comment: In every condition you want to remove `wandeling` data?

Comment: like this ? if (wandeling == false && type.equals("wandeling")

Comment: we want to remove wandeling data when the boolean wandeling is false and the type of the data is wandeling

Comment: Yes and when condition is true then check type from HashMap and remove it from ArrayList

Comment: How do you check the type and remove it from ArryList ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did an it works!

```
 for (int i = jsonlist.size()-1 ; i >= 0; i--) {
                    if (jsonlist.get(i).get(type).equals("wandeling") && wandeling == false) {
                        jsonlist.remove(i);
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Peraps you should use a class instead a map and use the stream api of java8

```
result = jsonlist.stream()
  .filter( x -> wandling || (!x.actType.equals("wandling") )
  .filter( x -> fiets || (!x.actType.equals("fiets") )
  .filter( x -> excursie|| (!x.actType.equals("excursie") )
  .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

It should looks like that

Comment: I dont understand this code ,could you explain this a bit more?